# WatchService / WatchEvent / Path from event

Tags: java, java-7

I'm recursively watching a directory (and therefore all subdirs and files) for changes.

It seems, if I'm creating or deleting a directory or file in a subdirectory of the root-dir to watch the Path which is included in the WatchEvent instance one receives (via context()) has no Parent and therefore `rootDirToWatch.resolve(event.context())` is not returning the Path I like to have.

For instance:

`/home/johannes/test` is watched, then I'm creating a new directory in `/home/johannes/test/foo/bar` named `baz`, I'm getting a new Path instance which is
`/home/johannes/test/baz` instead of `/home/johannes/test/foo/bar/baz`

Any suggestions what's going wrong?

I'm simply using a visitor to watch for all subdirectories in a certain root-directory to watch (watching a whole directory with all it's descendants):

```
@Override
public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(final Path pDir, final BasicFileAttributes pAttrs)
    throws IOException
{
    checkNotNull(pDir);
    checkNotNull(pAttrs);
    pDir.register(mWatcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

Edit: I think I really have to use a visitor or at least register all subdirs with the watcher. As WatchEvent returns a relative path it's clear why it behaves as described, but I don't want to traverse the directory once more to find the path from the root-dir to watch to the added/deleted/modified File somewhere depper in the hierarchy.

Edit: I've found the solution ("indexing" the keys): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java

Comment: I found out the hard way that `WatchEvent<Path>.context()` always returns a `Path` relative to the current working directory (even if you call `toAbsolutePath()` on it).  Although the documentation _says_ it's relative, it doesn't seem to work the way common sense would dictate.

Thanks for mentioning the solution.  Indexing the keys appears to be the only way to get the correct path (e.g. `originalPath.resolve(event.context())`)

Answer (score 2):

Alan is right.

You should use the Watchable in the key.

Here's a Scala code from my app. I guess you will be able to read it.

```
object FsNotifType extends Enumeration {
  val Create, Update, Delete = Value
}

case class FsNotif(notifType: FsNotifType.Value,path: Path)

object FsNotif {
  def apply(watchKey: WatchKey,event: java.nio.file.WatchEvent[_]): FsNotif = {
    val fsNotifType = event.kind() match {
      case StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE => FsNotifType.Create
      case StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY => FsNotifType.Update
      case StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE => FsNotifType.Delete
      case _ => throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown FS event kind: " + event)
    }
    val watchedPath = watchKey.watchable().asInstanceOf[Path]
    val relativePath = event.context().asInstanceOf[Path]
    val absolutePath = watchedPath.resolve(relativePath)
    FsNotif(fsNotifType,absolutePath)
  }
}
```

This works fine, but take care of some corner cases:

```
/**
 * Returns the object for which this watch key was created. This method will
 * continue to return the object even after the key is cancelled.
 *
 * <p> As the {@code WatchService} is intended to map directly on to the
 * native file event notification facility (where available) then many of
 * details on how registered objects are watched is highly implementation
 * specific. When watching a directory for changes for example, and the
 * directory is moved or renamed in the file system, there is no guarantee
 * that the watch key will be cancelled and so the object returned by this
 * method may no longer be a valid path to the directory.
 *
 * @return the object for which this watch key was created
 */
Watchable watchable();
```

Sorry, I don't know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

The watchable() method will return the original Watchable so you can use it as the parent directory.