# Watchable() implementation in Watcher service

Tags: java, watch

I am facing the same problem which was described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205842/watchservice-watchevent-path-from-event) ,I have try to implemented my code using their solution although it's not java base solution. But I still not able to obtain what's expected and what I try to achieve also similar with their post
 Here is my folder structure.

```
C:/test/edit
  /test/edit/a
    /test/edit/a/new
  /test/edit/b
```

Here is my debugging statement

```
1
2
3
aa
bb
file path in registerAll method : C:\test\edit
cc
4
5
6
7
8
C:\test\edit\New folder
9
10
file:///C:/test/edit/New%20folder/
11
12
a
b
c
file path in register method : C:\test\edit\New folder
d

The new folder :C:\test\edit\New folderEvent :ENTRY_CREATE
5
6
7
8
C:\test\edit\a
9
10
file:///C:/test/edit/a/
11
12
a
b
c
file path in register method : C:\test\edit\a
d

The new folder :C:\test\edit\aEvent :ENTRY_CREATE
5
6
7
8
C:\test\edit\New folder
9
10
file:///C:/test/edit/New%20folder/
11
12
a
b
c
file path in register method : C:\test\edit\New folder
d

The new folder :C:\test\edit\New folderEvent :ENTRY_CREATE
5
6
7
8
C:\test\edit\b
9
10
file:///C:/test/edit/b/
11
12
a
b
c
file path in register method : C:\test\edit\b
d

The new folder :C:\test\edit\bEvent :ENTRY_CREATE
5
6
7
8
C:\test\edit\New folder\New folder
9
10
file:///C:/test/edit/New%20folder/New%20folder

The new file :C:\test\edit\New folder\New folderEvent :ENTRY_CREATE
5
6
7
8
C:\test\edit\New folder\new
9
10
file:///C:/test/edit/New%20folder/new

The new file :C:\test\edit\New folder\newEvent :ENTRY_CREATE
5
```

First, I will register `C:/test/edit`as my parent directory, after that try to create two new folder within the parent directory which is the `a` and `b`.All of the process appear correctly in my debugging statement because it's still able to capture the correct file path but when I try to create the new folder in `C:/test/edit/a/new`, the debugging statement start to give me wrong folder path and it's detect it's a file path,not a folder path. I faced this issues before and found out there's a post similar with my problem. But I try to use their comment for further modification and it's also not working. May I know am I doing the correct way because the source code in the link is using scala programming. 

My sample code

```
package file;

import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class file implements Runnable
{
    Path path;
    public void run()
    {
        try(WatchService svc = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) 
        {
            System.out.println("1");
            Map<WatchKey, Path> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
            System.out.println("2");
            path = Paths.get("C:/test/edit/");
            System.out.println("3");
            file.registerAll(path,svc,keyMap);
            System.out.println("4");
            WatchKey wk = null ;
           while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
           {
            do
            {

               try 
                {

                   System.out.println("5");
                    wk = svc.take();
                //  path = keyMap.get(wk.watchable());
                     for(WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents())
                     {
                         System.out.println("6");
                         WatchEvent.Kind<?> type = event.kind();
                         System.out.println("7");
                         path = (Path) wk.watchable();
                    //   Path object = (Path) event.context();
                    //   System.out.println(object.toAbsolutePath());
                         System.out.println("8");
                         Path child = path.resolve((Path)event.context());
                         System.out.println(child);
                         System.out.println("9");
                         URI fullPath = child.toAbsolutePath().toUri();
                         System.out.println("10");
                         System.out.println(fullPath);
                         Path newFilePath = Paths.get(fullPath);
                           if (Files.isDirectory(newFilePath, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS))
                            {
                               System.out.println("11");
                                if(type == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("12");
                                    register(newFilePath,keyMap,svc);
                                 //   URI uri = child.toUri();
                                  //  path = Paths.get(uri);
                                }

                             System.out.println("\nThe new folder :"+newFilePath+ "Event :" +type);  
                            }
                           else
                           {
                            System.out.println("\nThe new file :"+child+ "Event :" +type);  
                           }
                     }
                } 
               catch (InterruptedException e) 

                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }while(wk.reset());

           }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static Path register(Path newFilePath, Map<WatchKey, Path> keyMap, WatchService svc) throws IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("a");
        Files.walkFileTree(newFilePath.toAbsolutePath(),new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
        {

           public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path newfilePath, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
           {
               System.out.println("b");
               if(attrs.isDirectory())
               {
                   System.out.println("c");
                   keyMap.put(newFilePath.register(svc, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE),newFilePath);
                   System.out.println("file path in register method : "+newFilePath);
               }
               System.out.println("d");
               return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
           }
        });

return newFilePath;

    }
    private static Path registerAll(Path path,  WatchService svc,Map<WatchKey, Path> keyMap) 
    {

         try {
            Files.walkFileTree(path.toAbsolutePath(),new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
                     {

                        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
                        {
                            System.out.println("aa");
                            if(attrs.isDirectory())
                            {
                                System.out.println("bb");
                                keyMap.put(path.register(svc, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE),path);
                                System.out.println("file path in registerAll method : "+path);
                            }
                            System.out.println("cc");
                            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                        }
                     });
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      return path;
    }
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        file f = new file();
        Thread t = new Thread(f);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the similar post you were looking at?

Comment: in the link that I provided in my post, I having the same problem like what had been describe in the post, so I try to implement their solution in my code but I can't make it happen because the code is in scala. I am not sure I am doing it correctly in java or not

Comment: is it a bug? because what I had found out in oracle website for this issue which facing by others people, they say this is a limitation due to java library and window